# Laravel VueJs Pagination Keep the same page number after update

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, pagination, laravel-pagination

I'm having some trouble with pagination
I get data by the api from laravel backend and start navigating by **laravel-vuejs-pagination package**

```
<Pagination :data="laravelData" @pagination-change-page="getResults" />
```

When i click to update an entry in the table and finish updating.
when i return to the table i start navigation from the top from page 1 not the page where i was working.
Is there anyway to get Results and **stay on same page**?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make this pagination script more complex

```
<Pagination :data="laravelData" :limit="1" @pagination-change-page="page => getResults(page, per_page, orderColumn, orderDirection)"></Pagination>
```